# Subversion Edge SSL

Tags: ssl, svn, subversion-edge

We've got Subversion Edge installed successfully and I need to secure it with a SSL certificate rather than the generated one.

I have a cert in the windows cert store, I need to export this to .crt and .key.

Does anyone know what tools I should use to do it, or If i can do it in windows?

is it openssl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, use OpenSSL.

You'll export a PKCS12 file from windows (make sure you include the private key), and you'll convert it to X509:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.pem -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -out cert.key -nocerts -nodes
```

Comment: perfect thanks, my first exposure to openssl :) nice little tool